# Storing variables for different discord servers

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to store different data for each server I'm setting my bot for I have looked through many forums and haven't found anything that fits my need, Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def pop(ctx, arg):
    global pop2
    pop2 = arg

    URL = 'https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/rust/' + arg
    page = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find("h2").get_text()
    title = title.replace('Connect', '')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    page = soup.find('dl', class_='css-1i1egz4')

    pop = page.find("dt", text="Player count")

    status = page.find("dt", text="Status")

    status1 = status.findNext("dd").get_text()
    pop1 = pop.findNext("dd").get_text()
    if status1 == "offline":
        colour = 0xff0000
    elif status1 == "online":
        colour = 0x33ff0a
    elif status1 == "dead":
        colour = 0xff0000
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=status1, color=colour)
    embed.add_field(name="Server", value=URL, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="pop", value=pop1, inline=False)
    await ctx.send("The server has been set to:")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? just storing per-guild data? you could [json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) on a small scale, or look into larger databases like [MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) or [MongoDB](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp)

Comment: How would I store it as a JSON on discord.py?

Comment: `json.load(openFile)` will return a python dictionary, then to save it `json.dump(dictionary, openFile)`